# How do you find a test location?

Tags: license

I'm new to ham and I'm wondering how to find test locations/study guides. I heard about this from a friend.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the website. http://www.arrl.org/find-an-amateur-radio-license-exam-session Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this link https://www.hamradiolicenseexam.com/where-to-take-amateur-radio-exam.htm Hope this was helpful

Comment: Hi Jeyden, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  BTW we recommend not posting just links as answers.  If the linked page contains information, then we recommend summarizing the information in the answer in case the link rots.  When the information is impossible to summarize, like this case, then a little description helps.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in the US, start with the ARRL License Manual, it costs $32.95 [from the ARRL](https://www.arrl.org/shop/Ham-Radio-License-Manual/) or you can find it at any bookseller. The ARRL, or the American Radio Relay League, is the national association for amateur radio and their web site also has a wealth of information for the aspiring ham, including a [search for exam sessions](http://www.arrl.org/find-an-amateur-radio-license-exam-session). Also, the FCC recently posted a [public notice (PDF)](https://docs.fcc.gov/public/attachments/DA-20-467A1.pdf) stating that "nothing in the FCC’s rules prohibits remote testing" so once you locate a local VE (Volunteer Examiner) you can ask them about whether they offer that if you're concerned about testing in person during the current pandemic. The ARRL has some [more information](http://www.arrl.org/news/remotely-administered-amateur-exam-systems-showing-promise) on the topic of remote testing.

The best study guide I have found is the KB6NU No-Nonsense guides; the Technician guide is available [as a PDF for free](https://www.kb6nu.com/study-guides/). Technician is the first level of licensing and is also what the ARRL book prepares you for.

These two resources work together, you will want both of them. The License Manual goes in depth into the topics you will need to learn and is essential to get an understanding of all you need to know to not only pass the test but to set up and operate your station safely and effectively. The KB6NU study guide is the refresher you'll want to cram just before the test, as it includes every test question and its answer with just enough context to get the gist, without any of the multiple-choice wrong answers to distract you - but it doesn't explain anything in depth so without having first studied the manual you'll quickly be lost.

Finally, you'll want to take some practice tests. A popular resource is HamStudy.org. The website has [flashcards and practice tests](https://hamstudy.org/tech2018) along with condensed explanations, similar to KB6NU's guides, and can keep track of your progress as you take the practice tests as many times as you want until you feel comfortable that you can pass the test. They also have an app for $3.99 that lets you do all of that offline.

Good luck! It's a very rewarding hobby and I'm glad you're interested in joining us on the air!

Comment: Your answer covers studying for test, but the question was where to find a location to take the test.

Comment: There were two other answers already with links to find a testing location and I didn't have anything to add to that, so I figured I'd answer the other half of the question, which was study guides.

Comment: @Jim I found some more pertinent info about testing than just the other answers' links, so I added that.